# Looking for a way to control a tab before any HTML has loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey, browser-extension

I'm looking for a way to control a tab in Chrome or any other browser before any HTML has loaded.

I wrote a quick TamperMonkey script that repeatedly reloads a page checking for appointments, but the problem is that the site is sooooo horrible that it's only loading at all one time in 3 right now.  So I need a way to detect that and reload the page after ≈60 sec if it hasn't loaded.  Since it's not returning anything at all TamperMonkey has no access to anything and can't trigger `location.reload()`

Context: Trying to get a visa appointment in Berlin.  Refreshing the page endlessly, for literally days on end, is the only way to do that... ‍♂️

Comment: afaik, if you write proper chrome extension you can have access to [`chrome.tabs.reload`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-reload). ps. you could just find tons of page reload/refresh extension in the wild.

Comment: @BagusTesa -- I'm not just refreshing the page, I'm checking for content and clicking a button